# Algorithm complexity for minimum number of clique in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I have written an algorithm which solves the minimum number of clique in a graph. I have tested my backtracking algorithm, but I couldn't calculate the worst case time complexity, I have tried a lot of times.

I know that this problem is an NP hard problem, but I think is it possible to give a worst time complexity based on the code. What is the worst time complexity for this code? Any idea? How you formalize the recursive equation?

I have tried to write understandable code. If you have any question, write a comment.
I will be very glad for tips, references, answers.
Thanks for the tips guys:).

**EDIT**
As M C commented basically I have tried to solve this problem [Clique cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_cover)

Pseudocode:

```
function countCliques(graph, vertice, cliques, numberOfClique, minimumSolution)
    for i = 1 .. number of cliques + 1 new loop
        if i > minimumSolution then 
            return;
        end if
        if (fitToClique(cliques(i), vertice, graph) then
            addVerticeToClique(cliques(i), vertice);
            if (vertice == 0) then //last vertice 
                minimumSolution = numberOfClique
                printResult(result);
            else 
                if (i == number of cliques + 1) then // if we are using a new clique the +1 always a new clique
                    countCliques(graph, vertice - 1, cliques, number of cliques + 1, minimum)
                else 
                    countCliques(graph, vertice - 1, cliques, number of cliques, minimum)
                end if
            end if 
            deleteVerticeFromClique(cliques(i), vertice);
        end if
    end loop
end function


bool fitToClique(clique, vertice, graph) 
    for ( i = 1 .. cliqueSize) loop 
        verticeFromClique = clique(i)
        if (not connected(verticeFromClique, vertice)) then 
            return false
        end if
    end loop
    return true
end function
```

Code

```
int countCliques(int** graph, int currentVertice, int** result, int numberOfSubset, int& minimum) {
// if solution
if (currentVertice == -1) {
    // if a better solution
    if (minimum > numberOfSubset) {
        minimum = numberOfSubset;
        printf("New minimum result:\n");
        print(result, numberOfSubset);
    }
    c++;
} else {
    // if not a solution, try to insert to a clique, if not fit then create a new clique (+1 in the loop)
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSubset + 1; i++) {
        if (i > minimum) {
            break;
        }
        //if fit
        if (fitToSubset(result[i], currentVertice, graph)) {
            // insert
            result[i][0]++;
            result[i][result[i][0]] = currentVertice;
            // try to insert the next vertice
            countCliques(graph, currentVertice - 1, result, (i == numberOfSubset) ? (i + 1) : numberOfSubset, minimum);
            // delete vertice from the clique
            result[i][0]--;
        }
    }
}
return c;
}


bool fitToSubset(int *subSet, int currentVertice, int **graph) {
    int subsetLength = subSet[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < subsetLength + 1; i++) {
        if (graph[subSet[i]][currentVertice] != 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;


  }

void print(int **result, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int m = result[i][0];
        printf("[");
        for (int j = 1; j < m; j++) {
            printf("%d, ",result[i][j] + 1);
        }
        printf("%d]\n", result[i][m] + 1);
    }
}

int** readFile(const char* file, int& v, int& e) {
int from, to;
int **graph;
FILE *graphFile;
fopen_s(&graphFile, file, "r");

fscanf_s(graphFile,"%d %d", &v, &e);

graph = (int**)malloc(v * sizeof(int));

for (int i = 0; i < v; i ++) {
    graph[i] = (int*)calloc(v, sizeof(int));
}

while(fscanf_s(graphFile,"%d %d", &from, &to) == 2) {
    graph[from - 1][to - 1] = 1;
    graph[to - 1][from - 1] = 1;
}
fclose(graphFile);
return graph;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "minimum number of clique"?

Comment: thank you for your comment. Yes, I should mention this before. Example: if we have a graph with  3 vertices and 2 edges [1 - > 2, 3 - > 1] the we can divide this to 2 clique(subgraph): 1: [1->2], [3] or 3 clique: [1], [2], [3] subgraph. Other example 4 vertices 2 edges [1->2, 3-> 2, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 1] the minimum number of clique is 2: 1: [1->2, 3->2, 3->1] and 2: [4].

Comment: do you understand my description, or is it to complicate?

Comment: The problem you are trying to solve appears to be [minimum clique cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_cover). As for the code, it might have been better to arrange the code closer to what is shown [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking#Pseudocode) for readability. As for the worst case performance, from the code it's not clear what the worst case would actually look like. Thus it's probably somewhere between O(2^N) and O(N!). Hard to say which it's closer to.

Comment: ahh, thank you, I didn't know that this problem name is clique cover problem. 10 minutes and I provide a pseudocode.

Comment: I have updated with a pseudocode.

Comment: Yes you are all right, I updated. The second one not contains the +1, because no new clique has created. What do you think is better or I should describe the small add/deleteVertice functions. These are constant time operations. +1 for good notice

Comment: Ah it's probably fine. Now that I got the psudocode, I'm not sure what the performance is. It's definitely no worst than O(N!). The issue is that you are basically using an incremental method to build it. If done well it can be be O(N^2) or better, but I'm not sure that's the case here. It really depends on how quickly the K-value can be lower to it's actual value, and in the worst case, that could take some time, and thus isn't easy to solve.

Comment: where you get the O(N!) I can't fallow your thingking,.

Comment: I actually mean O(2^N) and not (N^2). As for O(N!), you might be right, O(N!) does seem excessive. After thinking about it a bit I recalled something mentioned in an answer to a question I previously asked that gave me the solution I was looking for, which turns out to be what you are also looking for (I think).

Comment: Actually O(N!) was right, although it's impossible as it would require a full graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity of your algorithm is very closely linked to listing [compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28number_theory%29#Examples) of an integer, of which there are O(2^N).

The compositions alone is not enough though, as there is also a combinatorial aspect, although there are rules as well. Specifically, a clique must contain the highest numbered unused vertex.

An example is the composition 2-2-1 (N = 5). The first clique must contain 4, reducing the number of unused vertices to 4. There is then a choice between 1 of 4 elements, unused vertices is now 3. 1 element of the second clique is known, so 2 unused vertices. Thus must be a choice between 1 of 2 elements decides the final vertex in the second clique. This only leaves a single vertex for the last clique. For this composition there are 8 possible ways it could be made, given by (1*C(4,1)*1*C(2,1)*1). The 8 possible ways are as followed:

```
(5,4),(3,2),(1)
(5,4),(3,1),(2)
(5,3),(4,2),(1)
(5,3),(4,1),(2)
(5,2),(4,3),(1)
(5,2),(4,1),(3)
(5,1),(4,3),(2)
(5,1),(4,2),(3)
```

The above example shows the format required for the worst case, which is when the composition contains the as many 2s as possible. I'm thinking this is still O(N!) even though it's actually (N-1)*(N-3)*(N-5)*...*(1) or (N-1)*(N-3)*(N-5)*...*(2). However, it is impossible as it would as shown require a complete graph, which would be caught right away, and limit the graph to a single clique, of which there is only one solution.

Given the variations of the compositions, the number of possible compositions is probably a fair starting point for the upper bound as O(2^N). That there are O(3^(N/3)) maximal cliques is another bit of useful information, as the algorithm could theoretically find all of them. Although that isn't good enough either as some maximal cliques are found multiple times while others not at all.

A tighter upper bound is difficult for two main reasons. First, the algorithm progressively limits the max number of cliques, which I suppose you could call the size of the composition, which puts an upper limit on the computation time spent per clique. Second, missing edges cause a large number of possible variations to be ignored, which almost ensures that the vast majority of the O(N!) variations are ignored. Combined with the above paragraph, makes putting the upper bound difficult. If this isn't enough for an answer, you might want to take the question to math area of stack exchange as a better answer will require a fair bit of mathematical analysis.